# JMeter: How to record a script for specific domain URLs?

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to capture a script using **HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder** in **JMeter3.0**. When I start start capturing, URLs from other domains for ex. `download.cdn.mozilla.net` are also getting captured. I don't want these URLs to be recorded, I want to record URLs for a specific domain only. 
So, how to achieve this in JMeter3.0?

**Note:** I tried using **URL Patters to Exclude** but as I can not predict the other domain URLs, I don't want to use this option.
I also tried **URL Patters to Include** by specifying a specific domain i.e. `^((?!DOMAINNAME).)*$`, but it is still recording the other domain URLs.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend breaking down your requirement into 2 parts:

1. Include your domain **only**
2. Exclude everything else

So, given I want to record [JMeter Home Page](http://jmeter.apache.org/) and filter out any external resources the relevant configuration would be:

- URL Patterns to Include: `.*jmeter.apache.org.*`
- URL Pattens to Exclude: `.*`

[image: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder]

Both inputs accept [Perl5-compatible regular expressions](http://www.regextester.com/pregsyntax.html) so double check if the values your'e providing match (or don't match) the URL patterns captured by JMeter.

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Excluding Domains From The Load Test](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732519-Excluding-Domains-from-the-Load-Test)

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the "URL Patterns to Exclude" filter added. Just having .*jmeter.apache.org.* was enough to get it working.

Comment: This suggestion is wrong, URL Patterns to Exclude .* blocks everything